# Shapes not tied to worksheets?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

ok so,

I was hoping to have some stuff in my excel app persist, as in hang around, and I want something a little more reliable than global variables as these are reset when code is edited or if say the app is halted. (which does often happen)

So I've been using shapes, and they work good, but they rely on at least one worksheet always being constant right? as shapes are tied to sheets, if the sheet with the shapes gets deleted the shapes go away. And the users often delete / add new sheets, theres no one sheet that is always a constant, and they wouldnt let me force that on them either.

so is there a way to make shapes tied to workbooks instead of sheets? so then if a sheet is deleted with shapes on it, the shapes wont disapear.

any help or other suggestions appeciated

### Edit

Thanks again to: @David Zemens for the answer that got me through, just in case anyone ever looks at this down the road, the code to add a named range is: workbook.Names.Add Name:="Name", RefersTo:="value" - you NEED to add refersto or it will error. you can put in a temp value like "temp" and set the value later, but you have to have refers to when you add

Comment: What sort of "stuff" are you trying to keep in the shapes?

Comment: *so is there a way to make shapes tied to workbooks instead of sheets? so then if a sheet is deleted with shapes on it, the shapes wont disapear.* -- Where would they go? You could probably do a custom event to handle this, but I think your approach is probably wrong to begin with, so I would not recommend complicating it further.

Comment: well one of the things for example is a file name. When a user opens the app, they load up data from a csv, and I want to save the file name from that file. I've tried using a global variable but they get wiped out often enough on me, so I made a hidden shape that the user cant see, and I set its text property to the name of the file when they load it. that way, later on when I want to use that I have it. it's much more reliable. but If they happen to delete the sheet to which ive added that shape, poof, gone goes the shape and that file name.

Comment: how would you suggest making data persist other than global variables or shapes? by data i just mean several different strings.

Comment: Named Ranges can be attached to a Workbook (or a worksheet) and would be good for storing strings. Another alternative would be to use the XML Customer Data.  I will try to write an answer that demonstrates both (I have never really used the latter, but I am familiar with it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Named Ranges to save string data between sessions. They can be children of the Workbook or of specific Worksheets. You will want the former.  From the Formula Ribbon, Names Manager, Define Name like so:

[image]

Then, in your VBA, you can retrieve and set this range's value like:

```
Public Const CSVFileName as String = "sFileName"

Sub YourSubroutine()

Dim nm As Name
Set nm = ActiveWorkbook.Names(CSVFileName)

'Get the value:

MsgBox Replace(Replace(nm.Value, "=", vbNullString), """", vbNullString)

'Set the value:

nm.Value = "C:\documents\filename.CSV"

End Sub
```

The value associated with the Named Range persists beyond runtime, it is basically a property of the workbook.

I will post this now for you to review.  I will try to work up an example of the XML Customer Data, and will revise my answer with that, later.

Comment: thats awsome! I think that will work much better than shapes and be more reliable :D I'm going to test that out. Do post the xml customer data example too, and i'll check it out as well, and if I like one or the other I'll mark your answer :D

Comment: I did some digging I remember Customer Data from Powerpoint, there is something similar with CustomXMLPart in Excel but I am not too familiar with it, and frankly the Named Range approach should work for you.

Comment: it does indeed so you probs dont need to bother with it. I can research it anyways if i decide the named range isnt working. I like it too because the loading of the data is in a function, and users can use it for however many diff sheets, and each time they do it, I can make a named range with the name if the new sheet, and then I can have each file name stored in a named range that shares the name if the sheet, so I could go `Activeworkbook.names(Activesheet.name)` and it would get the name of the file that was used to populate the particular sheet!